# Problem inserting watermark in a pdf file with varying page-size in iText

Tags: itext, watermark

When I am trying to add a image as watermark at absolute position while absoluteX=10f and absolute y = rectangle.getLeft()+ (rectangle.getWidth()-image.getPlainWidth());

For some page-sizes, the image does not get added at absoluteX=10f have to increase it to 300f or more. How to correctly fetch the absolute position for the left.

Comment: What pagesizes are the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the page's crop box and position your text relative to that.  Note also that the bottom left corner need not be 0,0, and that **pages can be rotated**.

I've seen landscape pages generated three ways:

11"x8.5"

8.5x11 @ 90 degrees
8.5x11 @ 270 degrees

(fortunately I've never seen 11x8.5 @ 180, or I might have to Severely Harm someone on general principles)

"Portrait" pages are nigh-universally generated as 8.5"x11" (or whatever your measurements might be).  In my > a decade working with PDF, I have yet to see a rotated portrait page.  Legal, but stupid.

So, to get your correct bbox and rotate your text into position, you'd need something like:

```
final double TOP_OFFSET = 10.0 + IMAGE_HEIGHT; // or whatever
final double RIGHT_OFFSET = 15.0 + IMAGE_WIDTH;

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader( path );
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper( reader, outStream );

Rectangle cropBox = reader.getCropBox( 1 );
int rotation = reader.getPageRotation( 1 );
PdfContentByte content = stamper.getOverContent( 1 ); // first page

AffineTransform transform;
double xOffset, yOffset;
switch( rotation ) {
  case 0:
    xOffset = cropBox.getRight() - RIGHT_OFFSET;
    yOffset = cropBox.getTop() - TOP_OFFSET;
    transform = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance( xOffset, yOffset );
    break;
  case 90:
    // some other transformations here
    break;
  case 180:
    // and here
    break;
  case 270:
    // and here.
    break;
};

content.transform( transform );
content.addImage( waterMarkImage );

stamper.close();
```

I often find I have to blow the page size up by Quite A Bit in order to find out where I'm going wrong with my transformations.  Say +1000 to each border on the media box (and crop if present).

```
PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.getPageN(1);
PdfArray boxes[] = {pageDict.getAsArray( PdfName.MEDIABOX ), pageDict.getAsArray( PdfName.CROPBOX ) };
float mods[] = {-1000, -1000, 1000, 1000 }
for (int i = 0; i < boxes.length; ++i) {
  if (boxes[i] == null)
    continue; // crop boxes are optional
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
    PdfNumber curVal = boxes[i].getAsNumber(j);
    PdfNumber newVal = curVal.getFloat() + mods[j];
    boxes[i].set( j, newVal );
  }
}
```

Now, when you screw up your transformations (I inevitably do), you'll be able to see HOW you screwed up, and fix it.